# reg expression matching 8 latin character and numbers exactly

Tags: regex, unicode

I would like to have a regular expression matching *8 characters **exactly*** containing ***only*** latin letters and numbers, but not only digits. I have tried the following:

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]{8}$/
```

But it is not working. How can I alter the regular expression to limit the character number to *8*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\D)[a-zA-Z\d]{8}$
```

The idea is:

- `^$` - from the start til the end
- `(?=.*\D)` - there is at least one non-digit character (using [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))
- `[a-zA-Z\d]{8}` - 8 letters or numbers

Positive lookaheads match zero characters. They are basically used to ensure a condition is met for the following characters. `.*\D` means *after any amount of characters (`.*`), there is a non-digit character (`\D`)*.

Comment: can you please explain what does  (?=.*\D) mean?

Comment: Characters are **latin**, possible unicode characters too.

Comment: @ndn, per OP `but at least one digit`, shouldn't your pattern be `^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8}$` now it is matching `abcdefgh`

Comment: @alphabravo, I had screwed the question with my edit. It was originally *"not only numbers"*. Fixed the question, thanks.